# Laravel - How to convert Stdclass object to Array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing this problem when use database in Laravel. How can i convert that to Array the most simpletest?

```
$data = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Comment: Why not using Laravel Models? In that way you'll end up with a collection of results including the `toArray()` method which converts the full array (and children) to an array.

Comment: I think so too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this. this will return array of objects.

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode($data, true));
```

***Updated**

if you want to convert all nested properties to the array, try this.

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode($data, true), true);
```

Comment: This will return an array of objects.

Comment: json_decode(json_encode($data, true), true);
This will return array of arrays.

Comment: The comment by Sumit just above works for me, in fact... it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

`get()` will return a collection. If you want to get an array of objects,  use the `toArray()` method:

```
$data->toArray();
```

If you want to convert every object to an array too, do this:

```
$data->map(function($i) {
    return (array)$i;
})->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually run into this problem when I use DB::select and manually write my sql:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT *
                FROM ba_pics ba
                INNER JOIN pages pgs
                    ON ba.service_page_id = pgs.id';

    $baPics = DB::select($sql);
    $baPics = json_decode(json_encode($baPics, true), true);


    return view('beforeAndAfter',['baPics'=>$baPics, 'lodata'=>'no lodata yet']);
```

Here is another way using PHP's array_map function:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT *
                FROM ba_pics ba
                INNER JOIN pages pgs
                    ON ba.service_page_id = pgs.id';

    $baPics = DB::select($sql);

    $baPics = array_map(function($i) {
        return (array)$i;
    }, $baPics);

    return view('beforeAndAfter',['baPics'=>$baPics, 'lodata'=>'no lodata yet']);
```